# Как работает WebPack в Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-2017, angular

WebPack интегрирован в Visual Studio 2017?

Хоть я его и не конфигурировал, то все равно делает какую-то работу в момент сборки проекта. В корне самого проекта так же нету файла конфигурации.

Так каким же образом он работает? Visual Studio сама ему какие-то настройки подкилывает?

Comment: нет, он интегрирован в angular-cli

Comment: Т.е он использует какие-то дефолтные настройки и если я создам в корне конфигурационный файл, то будут использоваться эти настройки?

Comment: angular использует свои внутренние оптимизационные настройки и не обращает внимания на любые файлы созданные в корне

Comment: @overthesanity Хм... а раньше такого не было? Просто на метаните  в мануале создания приложения фигурирует его конфигурирование.

Comment: на метаните туториал создавался в 45 году когда была 2 версия angular :))) там просто апдейтят версию в package.json но не сам туториал

Comment: @overthesanity ну если оно действительно так, то оформите ответом